# Error while installing RAD Studio Community Edition

Tags: delphi, installation

I'm not sure if I'm asking my question in a right place or not, however, this is what I am facing now:
I was working on a FireMonkey project (to be specific, I was changing and designing the interface in Android Phone view) and suddenly I got an error and as far as I can recall the message was like this:

```
RAD Studio Exception Access Violation in module bds.exe at 00085e4a.....
```

I searched and did whatever I could, but there was no luck at all and after a day of search and try, I decided to reinstall it. I uninstalled it first, downloaded last Community edition and tried to install, but after accepting the license agreement and entering Serial number, while Installing Main Application Files I receive another error which says:

```
Unable to execute file:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\bds.exe

CreateProcess failed: code 2.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

as it shown in this image:

[image: Unable to execute file:C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\bds.exe. CreateProcess failed: code 2. The system cannot find the file specified.]

I almost tried everything and searched a lot for a solution and came up with nothing.

- Uninstalled it several times.
- Removed everything related to Embarcadero, RAD Studio or bds.exe through all my computer files and even registry.
- Disabled antivirus.
- Launched as administrator.
- Made a fresh new account for my windows.

It would be great if someone could offer a suggestion to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: "*I'm not sure if I'm asking my question in a right place or not*" - technical support questions about the IDE itself should be sent to [Embarcadero's Customer Support](https://www.embarcadero.com/support) directly. That being said, this exact issue was discussed on the Delphi-PRAXiS forum just 2 weeks ago: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/8315-c-builder-104-free-version-installation-fails-createprocess-errorcode-2/?tab=comments#comment-70412

Comment: @RemyLebeau, going for technical support was last thing I did right before post the question here, in support contact form, Community Edition was not supported and not listed in Product Selection combobox, however I sent my issue there too.
today first thing i did was removing Oracle VirtualBox, it was installed along side Genymotion (emulating android and debugging my app) it seems my problem is solved as it discussed in the page you placed the link. unfortunately it didn't came up in my searches. thanks for comment and link, it was helpful, i wish i could accept comment as answer.